# How to log for each script using logging (python)

Tags: python, logging

Im having an issue where currently I use two loggings where each script has its own logging. I have even used `filename="Test1/Logs/hello.txt` and Test2 for second script so the filename is seperated. My problem is that whenever I run a script, it saves only to one folder and in my case is Test1. It doesn't never logs into Test2 folder even though I run test2.py script which should save to the Test2 folder logs.

What I have done is:

```py
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
# CLASS A
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
logging.basicConfig(
    filename='{}{}.txt'.format(/Test1/Logs, datetime.now().strftime("%a %d %B %Y %H_%M_%S")),
    filemode='a',
    level=logging.INFO,
    format='[%(asctime)s]:%(levelname)s:%(funcName)s - %(message)s',
    datefmt=datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S.%f")[:-3]
)

loggingError = logging.getLogger()
logging.warning("Starting: {}".format(datetime.now().strftime("%a %d-%B-%Y %H:%M:%S")))


class A:

    def __init__(self):
        self.logging = loggingError


    def aW1wb3J0RmlsZXM(self):
        self.logging.error(sys.exc_info(), exc_info=True)
```

```py
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
# CLASS B
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
logging.basicConfig(
    filename='{}{}.txt'.format(/Test2/Logs, datetime.now().strftime("%a %d %B %Y %H_%M_%S")),
    filemode='a',
    level=logging.INFO,
    format='[%(asctime)s]:%(levelname)s:%(funcName)s - %(message)s',
    datefmt=datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S.%f")[:-3]
)

loggingError = logging.getLogger()
logging.warning("Starting: {}".format(datetime.now().strftime("%a %d-%B-%Y %H:%M:%S")))


class B:

    def __init__(self):
        self.logging = loggingError


    def aW1wb3J0RmlsZXM(self):
        self.logging.error(sys.exc_info(), exc_info=True)
```

```py
import A
import B

def main():

        if True:
            B.main()
            break

        if False:
            A.main()
            break


if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        main()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

as you can see the only difference between loggings are the folder name **filename** and yet even if I run Class B it still saves to Class A folder. What is the reason for that?

UPDATED TO EACH SCRIPT:

```py
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
file_handler = logging.FileHandler('{}{}.txt'.format(logsPath, datetime.now().strftime("%a %d %B %Y %H_%M_%S")))
formatter = logging.Formatter('[%(asctime)s]:%(levelname)s:%(funcName)s - %(message)s', "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")
file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(file_handler)
logger.warning("Starting: {}".format(datetime.now().strftime("%a %d-%B-%Y %H:%M:%S")))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because when you `import A` all the code inside of the file runs. Specifically the call to `basicConfig`. The way this function works is that it only has an effect if logging is not configured already, otherwise it does nothing. So when you first `import A` logging is configured, and the second call to `basicConfig` in B doesn't have any effect.

This is documented well in the official python docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig).

Edit:
File logging per module is easier done by doing something similar to this in each of the files:

```
import logging
local_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
local_logger.addHandler(logging.FileHandler('filename.log', 'a'))
local_logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

Comment: Ohhh, what do you suggest in that case to do? maybe to have the import inside the If statements in the main()?

Comment: Use a different logger for each file. `logging.getLogger('fileA')`. And don't use basicConfig , since your use case isn't basic.

Comment: Yeah, that is the way. I have also extended my answer to show the basic idea.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks alot! I didnt knew about this. Guess we learn something new everyday! =D

Comment: Also I assume this will start on both scripts if I have these config on? Even though I dont run etc class A?

Comment: Yes, this will immediately create the log file. If you want the file only created when you first write a log you can instantiate the `FileHandler` with `delay=True` kwarg.

Comment: Hmm strange, it will writes as soon as I start it. but most likely because I have import in both or? at this moment it just creates the script without adding anything inside the logs.txt. and I do have delay=true